# strtotime fails on pubDates from RSS feeds?

Tags: php, date, rss, strtotime

Example:

`print strtotime('Sat, 03 Nov 2012 20:17:12 0000');`

prints nothing :(

And the date string appears to be correct..
it's:

`day name, day month name year hour:min:sec timezone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it you want to add a timezone correction. But the timezone requires a sign.

```
print strtotime('Sat, 03 Nov 2012 20:17:12 +0000');
```

This will work

Answer (score 3):

Valid formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Consider using DateTime objects, and the [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method

Answer (score 1):

```
print strtotime('03 Nov 2012 20:17:12');
```

**Output:** `1351988232`

This works perfectly. You should remove the `0000` and the day `(Sat)`